# Is a reboot required when installing a .deb package off-repo in Parrot OS?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, deb, parrotsec

I have just downloaded the .deb package for slack-desktop from the official site, however, when looking for it in the menu it didn't show up in the menu. Then I rebooted the PC and searched for the program in the menu and it appeared. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it again yet I still had to reboot the PC to see the program installed.

In Ubuntu, the program is usually installed straight away without reboot so I don't know if this behaviour in Parrot is normal or not since I wasn't ever told to reboot the machine to complete the installation. Could you please tell me based on your experience?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? And don't confuse a program being installed (its data have been copied to the right locations and you can launch it using its name in the command line) and appearing in the menu. The program _is_ installed, even if you don't see it in the menu.

Comment: I'm using MATE. Although you are right, it should appear in the menu straight away. That's what normally happens Ubuntu anyways. (I'm new in Parrot and haven't installed Slack ever in Ubuntu either).

Answer (score 2):

This should not be necessary. Nothing in the MATE desktop that ParrotOS ships requires a reboot.

So possibly, the packaging from the external source just isn't up to Debian/ParrotOS standards (which might very well be the reason it's an external repo!), and forgets to trigger the script that updates things. I can tell you that at least for other Linux distros, slack's packaging and adherence to desktop standards is not that great (that's sadly pretty typical for electron applications like the slack desktop client; maintainers don't give a hoot about keeping users' config directories free of cache files, that kind of laziness).

In any case, a reboot would not be necessary to trigger anything within your desktop environment. Logging out and back in should be the most, but even that *should* not be necessary.